# datatable fnReloadAjax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, datatable

I need to use icons but they disappear when I reload the datatable.

When I declare the datatable I use fnInitComplete

```
"fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
    $(".readable_row").button({icons:{secondary:"ui-icon-folder-open"}});
    $(".editable_row").button({icons:{secondary:"ui-icon-wrench"}});
}
```

Is there a way to use fnInitComplete with fnReloadAjax? Or maybe a to wait for fnReloadAjax to succeed in retrieving data and reloading the datatable?

Comment: The documentation suggests you could do the button initialisation in [a handler attached to the `draw` event](http://datatables.net/manual/events)

Comment: That did the trick thanks! Although I had to use `.delegate()` since I had an older version of jQuery, nevertheless please post that as your answer.

Comment: If I were comfortable enough with it I would have in the first place rather than comment :) You could [yourself post a short summary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) of what you did and tick it, so future readers could potentially find it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a handler attached to the draw event I was able to re-attach the icons. I didn't even have to use `fnInitComplete`.

Using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#example").on("draw", function() {
    $(".readable_row").button({icons:{secondary:"ui-icon-folder-open"}});
    $(".editable_row").button({icons:{secondary:"ui-icon-wrench"}});
});
```

I had to use `.delegate()` since I had an older version of jQuery :

```
$("body").delegate("#example", "draw", function() {
    $(".readable_row").button({icons:{secondary:"ui-icon-folder-open"}});
    $(".editable_row").button({icons:{secondary:"ui-icon-wrench"}});
});
```